# make a jruby program a windows service

Tags: windows-services

I have a JRuby program that I want to be a windows service. I have seen some things on creating a service with Ruby, but we don't want to install ruby on our client machines. It appears to be not supported in JRuby.

I created a dummy program to try this out:

```
path = "C:/tmp/my-svc.log"

if File.exists?(path)
    File.open(path,"a"){|f| f.write(" called again\n")}
else  
    File.open(path,"w"){|f| f.write(" called first time\n")}
end

while true do   
    sleep 5
    puts 'I am a service'
end
```

I did this:

Z:\play>sc.exe create "larz service 2.1" binpath= "C:\jruby-1.6.7.2\bin\jruby -S Z:\play\my-win-svc.rb" start= auto

[SC] CreateService SUCCESS

Trying to start it I got this error:

Z:\play>sc start "larz service 2.1"

[SC] StartService FAILED with error 193.

Z:\play>sc query "larz service 2.1"

```
SERVICE_NAME: larz service 2.1`
TYPE               : 10  WIN32_OWN_PROCESS`
STATE              : 1  STOPPED
WIN32_EXIT_CODE    : 0  (0x0)
SERVICE_EXIT_CODE  : 0  (0x0)
CHECKPOINT         : 0x0
WAIT_HINT          : 0x0
```

I have seen alot of posts on the web on different ways to create windows services, using initsrv.exe, powershell, running CMD, editing the registry and so on, but I am not sure what is really going on or if I need to call some API. It doesn't appear as if the other approaches add any specific start parameters that I could tell. In addition, I added code at the beginning of my test service to write to a file in /tmp and the file is not being written so when I try to start the program, it never actually is being executed.

Thanks ..

---

Ok, so I got a little farther, but still mystified

Z:\play>sc config "larz service 2.2" obj= EEE\lgud password= "Ssssssss@"

[SC] ChangeServiceConfig SUCCESS

Z:\play>sc start "larz service 2.2"

[SC] StartService FAILED 1069:

the service did not start due to a logon failure.

It seems I entered the correct format for user/pw as at other times it errored out on the config command.

Comment: Ok, so I got a little farther, but still mystified

    Z:\play>sc config "larz service 2.2" obj= EEE\lgud password= "Ssssssss@"

    [SC] ChangeServiceConfig SUCCESS

    Z:\play>sc start "larz service 2.2"

    [SC] StartService FAILED 1069:
    The service did not start due to a logon failure.

Answer (score 0):

If you are positive that the password is correct, perhaps the user you have specified doesn't have the right privileges to run as a service. Try entering the account information on the Windows Services Application (services.msc) [Log On tab](http://www.coretechnologies.com/WindowsServices/services-control-panel-log-on-tab.jpg), which will let you know if there is a problem with that user.

But beyond that, I don't see how you're going to get this going without Ruby installed. Your service's executable path is set to a .rb file -- what application do you expect Windows to launch to run that file, if not Ruby?

Comment: I was trying to use ruby just so that I could get something working to try to figure out where to go next. I also was thinking perhaps I could use something like the ocra gem to create a windows executable. I think they just don't want to have to install ruby on the client machines. At any rate, I have tried another attempt here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15394683/running-windows-service-in-ruby-on-windows-7  I am still having pretty much the same problem. I may try it on my personal laptop if I get a chance.