# running windows service in ruby on windows 7

Tags: ruby, windows-services

I am using this gem:
win32-service (0.7.2 x86-mingw32)

The gem has a demo_daemon.rb and a demo_daemon_ctl.rb in the example directory.
I have tried to run the example as a service using both ruby 1.8.7 and 1.9.3 and I get the error below.
The daemon tries to write to a log file, but it never reaches a point where the log file gets written. Even if I put a log write on startup of the script nothing gets written.

My machine is 64 bit.

Any ideas on what I can try or what could be the issue?

```
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/win32-service-0.7.2-x86-mingw32/lib/win32/se
rvice.rb:760:in `start': The service did not respond to the start or control req
uest in a timely fashion. (Win32::Service::Error)
        from demo_daemon_ctl.rb:75:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need use a service wrapper such as srvany . Here is the [Microsoft's guide](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/137890). Use full path for both ruby and the script in the "Application" parameter. And if something goes wrong under 64bit system, just put the srvany.exe in both windows/system32 and windows/sysWow64 folder.